# "Invalid API key. Please see https://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."

Tags: vue.js

Please Am trying to fetch the open weather api in my vue js web application
And this was the error have been getting please how can i fix this problem
This is the Error:
"Invalid API key. Please see https://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."

And this is my vue js code:

```
<template></template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from "@vue/runtime-core";
export default {
  setup() {
    const weatherData = ref([]);
    const latitude = ref("");
    const longitude = ref("");
    onMounted(() => {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          latitude.value = position.coords.latitude;
          longitude.value = position.coords.longitude;
        });
      } else {
        alert("Your Browser Doesn't support Geolocation");
        console.log("Your Browser do not Support Geolocation");
      }

      fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={${latitude.value}}&lon={${longitude.value}}&appid={dace6a593d778f8773c2fd033a16a91a}`
      )
        .then((data) => data.json())
        .then((response) => {
          weatherData.value = response;
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
    });
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Am expecting the Result
The json format please help

Comment: hey mate, your api key is string , so try to pass it as one, `appid=dace6a...` (without {})

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error. us this

```
`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${latitude.value}&lon=${longitude.value}&appid=dace6a593d778f8773c2fd033a16a91a`
```

Comment: Also, never  post your api keys!

Comment: Thanks I won't post it again. Thanks for helping